# Display bar charts in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, chart

I am trying to symbolize data as  bar charts in ArcMap. I have a feature class with two sets of data, and I want the bar charts next to each other on the map. The problem I am having is that the map will only display the bars if both sets of data are not Null. Is there a way to display all the bars with data? If I put 0 for the Nulls, then a flat bar appears, and I don't want that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option to exclude certain data in the layer itself. You could do this, and then it will graph everything else.

Select layer-> Options->Symbology-> Charts-> Exclusion-> SQL query "Field" IS NULL

This will make it so that all the null values do not appear in the bar graph. let me know if this solved it

Comment: I tried doing that. If one of the fields is NULL, then it removes both bars.

Comment: So you have 2 fields, and they may be populated in the following ways : both, none, or only one is populated while the other is null?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: Im assuming doing 2 bar charts is not an option ? Because if so, you could export the table, and only keep the second field, then exclude nulls from both, and graph

Comment: That is definitely an option. I'm thinking that's the way that I'm going to go.
I was trying to avoid that, because then I have to move the exported data to make sure they are next to each other, and not on top of each other.